# Visa for Honorary Research Fellow in the UK

Tags: visas, uk, student-visas

If a medical doctor wants to come to UK to spent a period of 1-year as an "honorary research fellow" (i.e., it is not paid by the UK academic institution, will not apply for UK funds, but want to cooperate with UK-based researcher in collaborative groups and research), **outside** the scheme of a formal exchange programme (i.e., wants to join a research group on its own, and it is obviously accepted as an honorary research fellow by the institution), what type of Visa should he/she apply for?

I am a little bit confused - it doesn't seem that this kind of application fit the "Student Visa", but also Tier 5 type Visa does not seem to be entirely appropriate here.

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A Visitor Visa? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/938632/visit-guidance-v10.0ext.pdf#page33

Comment: The university will be able to advise on the visa requirements: they will probably deal with this frequently.

Comment: @Traveller yeah, a Standard Visitor visa is the option that most likely seems to fit the case - this should let a medical doctor do the research stuff even without being paid by the UK institution, but it is somewhat unclear what are the limits and boundaries of the visa in this specific situation, especially in terms of eligibility...

Comment: Standard eligibility rules apply, plus the additional rules in V10.1 if seeking 12 month entry as an academic https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

Comment: This site is for short term travel like vacations. We have a site called [expatriates.se] which is for living and working abroad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate option is a Standard Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Entry, validity, suitability, and eligibility requirements are set out in Immigration Rules Appendix V: Visitor, V1.1 - V4.6

All applicants must meet all of the eligibility requirements in V 4.2. to V 4.6, and an academic seeking a 12-month entry clearance must also meet [the additional requirements at V 10.1](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor#additional-eligibility-requirements-for-academics-seeking-to-come-to-the-uk-for-more-than-6-months):

> (a) intend to undertake one of the permitted activities in Appendix
> Visitor: Permitted Activities at PA 11.2. for up to 12 months; and
>
> (b) be highly qualified within their own field of expertise; and
>
> (c) be currently be working in their field of expertise at an academic
> institution or institution of higher education overseas; and
>
> (d) provide a valid medical certificate if paragraph A39 and Appendix
> T of these rules apply.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

Eminent senior doctors or dentists must have been working for a number of years in their profession. They may come to the UK to take part in research, teaching or clinical practice as long as this remains incidental to their employment overseas. See the section entitled **Science, research and academia** in https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/938632/visit-guidance-v10.0ext.pdf#page33

Comment: thank you for your answer. What it is unclear to me if what are the criteria to be defined as "highly qualified". Furthermore, what is considered "working [...] at an academic institution?" Have a tenure track, be a PhD or post-graduate student... it is unclear to me and I have no idea on what basis this criteria are applied

Comment: ‘Highly qualified’ and ‘working’ in reference to medical doctors is explained in the section entitled ** Science, research and academia** of the Visit Guidance published by the Home Office. I’ve added the information to my answer